# Function $f(x)$ similar to exp(x) where $-f(x)$ is approximately $f(-x)$

Tags: exponential-function

I am wondering if there is a function $f(x)$ "similar" to the exponential function $\exp(x)$ such that:

$-f(x) \approx f(-x)$

I would also like $f(x)$ to have the following property:

$\frac{{f(a)}}{{f(b)}} = f(a - b)$

Or alternately,

$\frac{{f(a)}}{{f(b)}} \approx f(a - b)$

Comment: $-\exp (x) $ is *not* approximately $\exp(-x).$ Perhaps you mean't something else? Anyway, there are many functions fitting your description. For example, every odd function.

Comment: $\exp(z) >0$ always, what do you mean by $-\exp(x) \approx \exp(-x)$???

Comment: Do you mean $\sinh(x)$ by chance?

Comment: Yes, every odd function would indeed fit the description, and I have now updated my original question to remove the spurious $-\exp(x) \approx \exp(-x)$.  Thanks for these insightful comments.

Comment: You can't have exact equality for both $-f(x)=f(-x)$ and $f(a)/f(b)=f(a-b)$, because then $-1=f(x)/f(-x)=f(2x)$ for all $x$, which violates $-f(x)=f(-x)$.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Thanks for your comment. Does $-1=f(x)/f(-x)=f(2x)$ only hold when $a = b$, or are you saying that it is impossible for an odd function to have the property that $f(a)/f(b) = f(a-b)$?

Comment: If $f(a)/f(b)=f(a-b)$ for all $a$ and $b$, then for any $x$ we can let $a=x$ and $b=-x$ to get $f(x)/f(-x)=f(x-(-x))=f(2x)$. But if $f$ is odd, $f(-x)=-f(x)$, so $f(x)/f(-x)=-1$. Putting the two together means that $f(2x)=-1$ for any $x$, but then $f$ can't be odd: a contradiction. So it is not possible for $f$ to be odd and satisfy $f(a)/f(b)=f(a-b)$ at the same time.

Comment: @RahulNarain: That's a really interesting little proof.  Thanks for clarifying this.  I suppose that I am going to have to settle for $f(a)/f(b) \approx f(a-b)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be interested in the [hyperbolic sine "sinh"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function). It is antisymmetric and its asymptotic behaviour for $x\to\infty$ is similar to the one of the exponential function.

Comment: That's just lovely, $\sinh(x)$ is really beautiful. +1 for suggesting this as well, and it does indeed fit the $-f(x) = f(-x)$ property.

Comment: It is worth noting that $\sinh(x)$ is, in its heart, a exponential function.

Comment: If $\sinh(x) = (1/2)(\exp(x) - \exp(-x))$, note that when $x \rightarrow +\infty$ it approaches $(1/2)\exp(x)$ in behaviour.

Comment: @IanMateus: Thank you. So I think that what is being implied is that $\sinh(a)/\sinh(b) \approx \sinh(a-b)$ for $x \rightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: At first sight, yes. I think one can put more rigour at this and get an idea of the power of these approximations.

Comment: @IanMateus: Thanks for clarifying this, Ian.  I think that $\sinh(x)$ may indeed fit the bill.

Comment: @NicholasKinar Another interesting fact that may interest you is that $\sinh(x) + \cosh(x) = \exp(x).$

Comment: @IanMateus: Thanks Ian; that is also insightful.  To correct an error that I made in the comments above, I meant $\frac{{\sinh (a)}}{{\sinh (b)}} \approx \exp (a - b)$.  I've found that the approximation is sufficiently good for $a,b$ greater than 5.

Comment: @NicholasKinar Nice!